# Masked Load/Store

Tags: arm, simd, intrinsics, neon

I am writing a function using neon intrinsics to optimize some matrix operations and I need to treat special cases (like reaching the end of an array with a size which is not a multiple of the register size).

I would prefer if there were a SIMD instruction in neon to do something like this (like the masks in AVX).

Is there any way you can do a masked load/store using Neon intrinsics?

Comment: [Here](https://www.community.arm.com/processors/b/blog/posts/coding-for-neon---part-2-dealing-with-leftovers)'s a blog post about the problem, but it doesn't directly address your masked load requirement.  NEON has single lane loads and stores which you can executed conditionally for each lane, but if you're only concerned with loading `n` consecutive values into a vector you can do that log-wise by using mixed lane sizes, as demonstrated [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/rs/+/master/cpu_ref/rsCpuIntrinsics_neon_Blend.S#484).

Comment: I'll try to find the time to write something proper, but I can't promise it'll be this year.  One thing to note is branch prediction.  If you frequently change the mask for the same block of code this can turn out very slow, but it's common to use the same tail many times over when dealing with rectangular data like images.